# Equivalent of Excel VALUE function for VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I need to convert a time value from the text format "hh:mm" to a number. The Value can also be negative and higher than 24 hours. I came up with the following formula to achieve this:

```
=IF(LEFT(B1)="-";VALUE(RIGHT(B1;LEN(B1)-1))*-1;VALUE(B1))
```

This works but since the actual value of B1 is another formula (using Index/Match), it makes everything complicated and unclear.

I thus considered creating a VBA function to deal with this but I can't find the appropriate counterpart of "VALUE" in VBA. Using the "Val" function doesn't really work as it expects a number format, not a time format. Using TimeValue works only as long as the value is less than 24:00.

```
Function TVALUE(txt As String)
  If Left(txt, 1) = "-" Then
    'MsgBox ("Negative")
    TVALUE = (TimeValue(Right(txt, Len(txt) - 1))) * -1
  Else
    TVALUE = TimeValue(txt)
  End If
End Function
```

[Example Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdWsR.png)

Any ideas on how I could solve this?

Comment: According to the Microsoft article [Add or subtract time](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-or-subtract-time-16aa6697-6d6e-49c1-8e2c-3398a7cad6ad), the format of the cells should be `[h]:mm;@` for accepting values larger than 24 hours.

Comment: @harrymc thanks for the tip. unfortunately, that one relates to formatting of the outputted values. In my case, the formula in VBA directly throws a #VALUE! error because the TimeValue function only takes values up to 23:59:59 according to the [TimeValue Function Spec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/timevalue-function)

Comment: You can't force TimeValue to do otherwise. You need to look for other ways of doing it.

Comment: This smells like very much an "XY problem". Why do you want the time as a value? I'd instead implore you to investigate how you manipulate time variables with DateAdd, Hour, Day and similar functions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said that B1 would actually be an INDEX/MATCH, which is making it unclear.

If you have the appropriate version of Excel, you can try this (replace B1 with your INDEX/MATCH formula):

```
=LET(x,B1,IF(LEFT(x)="-",VALUE(RIGHT(x,LEN(x)-1))*-1,VALUE(x)))
```

LET assigns the result of your INDEX/MATCH to the variable x, then re-uses it throughout the formula. x is just a name and you can use any name you want. I prefer to use a single letter as it makes the whole function shorter.

If that doesn't work and you must use VBA, then you need the following:

```
Function TVALUE(txt As String)
  If Left(txt, 1) = "-" Then
    'MsgBox ("Negative")
    TVALUE = Application.WorksheetFunction.NumberValue(Right(txt, Len(txt) - 1), ",", ".") * -1
  Else
    TVALUE = Application.WorksheetFunction.NumberValue(txt, ",", ".")
  End If
  
End Function
```

[WorksheetFunction.NumberValue](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.worksheetfunction.numbervalue)

[image]

Comment: Thanks @FlexYourData, that's what I needed: Application.WorksheetFunction.NumberValue

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SU.  Something similar to this might work:

```
Function TValue(ByVal txt)
    TValue = 0.0
    Dim a : a = Split(txt, ":")
    If 1 = UBound(a) Then
        If IsNumeric(a(0)) And IsNumeric(a(1)) Then
            TValue = (Abs(a(0)) / 24) + ((a(1) / 60) / 24)
            If InStr(txt, "-") > 0 Then TValue = -TValue
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Synopsis:

- Initialize the result as 0.0 for invalid strings
- If an hours:minutes string is passed, ensure the values are numeric
- If the hours and minutes are numeric, then calculate the time serialization value
- If a negative sign was found, negate the value

Some improvements could be made to explicitly check for valid string formats and whole numbers, but this should help to get you started.

Good luck.